# Generalizing linear duality via the $Hom$ functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, soft-question, duality-theorems

I am a beginner in category theory, so the following question could be either obvious or of no interest. Anyhow, I cannot find a statisfactory framing, and possibly an answer for the following question:
Can we generalize the notion of 'linear' duality to categories other than $Vect$ or $A$-mod? Is this construction ever related to forming the opposite of a category (so to duality in the proper categorical sense)?

Obviously the problem is ill posed in this form, so I tried to work it out with my limited knowledge.

First of all, fix a category $\mathcal{C}$, then it always make sense to form the opposite category $\mathcal{C}^{op}$.

In some categories anyhow, there is a particular 'dualizing' object $D$, so that $Hom(\cdot,D)$ is a contravariant endofunctor. For instance in the category of $A$-modules (and in particular in $Vect$), the base ring (field) $A$ is such.

> **Q1** Is there a way to charachterize abstractly those categories and one object (or possibly more) therein, so that we have a way to perform this construction and it makes some sense? Are there at least  other similarly relevant examples?

Obviously, a first obstruction to this is the fact that in general the $Hom$ functor is valued in $Set$ an not in our source category. But then there is also the 'meaningfulness' of this construction

> **Q2** In this situation, it may happen that the $Hom$ functor carries object to isomorphic ones, as in $FinVect$ though not naturally, and hence being contravariant reverses arrows but 'fixes' objects. Is there any relation to the formation of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ in this case?

Thanks for any help or hints and references

Comment: The notion of [dualizing object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizing+object+in+a+closed+category) might be of interest.

Comment: the notion of enriched category might be of interest, to understand how $hom$'s can live in something else than $Set$ (and for that, you might want to look into closed monoidal categories)